# remove duplicate user if they has same email

Tags: reactjs

if the user want to add exist email,then it will show a alert that 'user already exist',i have tried various array method like map,filter but i have failed.

```
const Todo = () => {
  const [getName, setName] = useState("");
  const [getEmail, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  const nameHandle = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };
  const emailHandle = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    if (getName !== "" && getEmail !== "") {
      const userDetails = {
        userId: uuidv4(),
        name: getName,
        email: getEmail,
      };
      setUser([...user, userDetails]);
    } 
  };

  const deleteUser=(e,userId)=>{
      console.log(userId);
    e.preventDefault();
    setUser(user.filter(value=>value.userId!==userId))
    console.log(user);
  }
```

Comment: where is ````deleteUser```` being called and where is ````userId```` being passed from?

Comment: solved , thank you . can you explain why other method are not working instead of some? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
if (user.some(value => value.email === getEmail)) {
    // email already used!
}
```

Comment: can u edit my code? i want to remove that user also.

Comment: solved , thank you . can you explain why other method are not working instead of some?